# Email.php new lines not working

Tags: php, email

I am using this to send registration emails:

```
sendMail($this->input->post('register_email'), $this->config->item('activation_sender_mail'), $this->config->item('server_name').'Account Creation', 'Hey '.$this->input->post('register_username').'r\n Thank you for your interest in contributing to the site.\r\n Just click this link to activate your account:\r\n <a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>');
```

But the mail i recieve is:

> Hey User!rn Thank you for you interest in contributing to the site.rn Just click this link to activate your account:rn link

I want to look like :

```
Hey user!
Thank you for you interest in contributing to the site.
Just click this link to activate your account:
link
```

Comment: You need to post the code of the `sendMail()` function, otherwise it's only guessing.

Comment: You can't expect formatted text when all you do is add it as a single string.

Comment: Using single quotes, `'\n' == 'n'`. Using double quotes, `"\n"` is a new line. This might be enough, but if you need HTML format, you'll need `'<br />'`.

Answer (score 5):

`\r\n` are used for sending plain-text. Since you've included an `<a>` element in your code, I'm going to assume that you're sending HTML email.

If that's the case, use either `<p>` tags to format the content, or `<br />` for new lines.

Comment: @user3913519 You may like to accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As your email is in html format, you must use

`<br />`

tags instead of \n\r.

Answer (score 0):

for me i use

```
<br/>
```

instead of r\n.
regards